# SSH autologin __without__ using keys :(

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I know it's insecure.

My school has a system that you can ssh into, but it runs a strange operating system (might be openVMS based, that's what the error messages indicate). They don't use keys, just a user/password, and then an internal application is started that actually authenticates the user. I got the u/p password from their website off of a config file, they don't care about security here.

I would like to just be able to type school_login as an alias and have it ssh fully in for me, skipping the type the password bit. Can I do this? If I add their public key, I will still be prompted for the password, right? Is there anyway I can get around it?

Thanks!

Comment: To be clear here... you're definitely not hacking your school network equipment, yes?

Comment: ha ha no, although this is definitely not the way _most_ students connect, I know a group of CS guys, including myself, that always ssh into the system. Saves the hassle of their clunkly client-software, which is simply an ssh client packaged with a config file ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) does this.

Comment: Works excellent for it's purpose! 

Quick example - 
sshpass -p your_pass_here ssh user@host

Comment: probably not a big issue in your case, but just for the record, it's not a good idea to include a password in a command line like that. The reason being that other users on your machine can get a process listing and see the password right there. Like I say, probably not an issue for you, since you probably don't have other users on your system, but I thought I'd mention it for the benefit of others. Expect in the other answer is a better solution for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to codge something up using [expect](http://expect.nist.gov/).