# Bash: controlling SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, controls

I have this bash file, which asks for IP, password, etc. for OpenSSH to a device.

Now, if i use `ssh root@ip`, i have to enter the password. This is really irritating. Secondly; i cannot let my script send commands to it.

This is what i want->

1. Not the password thing; i already found something; but it tells me the commands are not found?:

   `#!/usr/bin/expect -f`

   `spawn ssh root@$IPADDR`

   `expect "password:"`

   `sleep 1`

   `send "$rpass\r"`

   2. I want the user to be able to see some menus where it can choose from; after that; every command is done for him. So like a new window, or something like that?
   3. I do not want to use:
      -Any external stuff
      -No extra editing of the SSH connection

BASH INFO: GNU Bash, v. 4.0.33(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu), running on Linux Mint. But it got to be available for several linux distro's, and also on Mac?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449932

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many tools go to great lengths to prevent what you are doing. I recommend using ssh public keys to solve this problem instead of passwords.

The big alternative is to write your own modified ssh client based on the open source so as to take control of the password management.

Oh, well, I forgot. You can probably outsmart this with a pty, since then /dev/tty will be what you control. `expect` might help you with this.

Comment: as i stated: `No extra editing of the SSH connection`; including public keys.

Comment: I could start editing the ssh client, but it's going to take some time. Thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 17):

The proper way to do this without storing passwords in plaintext on your machine is with ssh. First run:

> ssh-keygen

This will generate a new SSH key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. After that simply run:

> ssh-copy-id user@my.server.com

If you're on OS X or another machine that does not have "ssh-copy-id" there are one-line [alternatives](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/188/copy-your-ssh-public-key-to-a-server-from-a-machine-that-doesnt-have-ssh-copy-id) such as this one:

> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@machine "mkdir ~/.ssh; cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"

Ultimately you just need to append the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on your local machine to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote server. How you do that is up to you, the above are just quick shortcuts to do that.

Answer (score 2):

[Expect](http://expect.nist.gov/) is the usual tool for automating interactive sessions.

Comment: i already gave this in my question, but i do not have spawn and send either. Now, i really have to download them, put in my folder? So harsh.

Comment: Those are expect commands, you ARE running the script through expect, yes?

Comment: Spawn and send are commands that `expect` recognizes. They aren't separate downloads. You need to make sure that the path to `expect` is correct for your system in the shebang. You will also probably want to use the `interact` command in your `expect` script.

Comment: how can i use expect as something to share with others?

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to go is to copy the keys as has been said here. To add something to the conversation, there are cases where `sshpass` can be handy.

The question asks specifically about scripting in a system with SSH. If it is the development of an embedded system, it can be useful to combine `sshpass` with command line options, as it reads on this post

```
sshpass -p raspberry ssh pi@192.168.0.145
```

this can be combined with

```
ssh -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no pi@192.168.0.145
```

to avoid confirmation questions that prevent scripting from happening.

Again, only use this in development systems where different machines share an IP and security is not important.

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/02/22/easy-passwordless-ssh-with-sshh/

Answer (score 1):

Use ssh-keygen to create a public key for your machine, then copy your local `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or `~/.ssh/identity.pub` to the remote system, in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

You may need to tighten the permissions on the authorized_keys file: chmod 600

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Paramiko](http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different/)? It's a Python-library for interacting with SSH.

Comment: Can i interact with it trough bash?

Comment: Depends on what you want. If you'd provided more details about what problem you're *really* trying to solve, it'd be easier to help.

Comment: What i try to do is using bash make a sort of ssh client. I really like this Paramiko idea; but what i need to do is interacting it with bash. The code is written in bash and i want it to keep it like that. I do not know Python; i am a beginning programmer. Anyway; what i want to do is like (almost) everything what's possible with ssh; the password thing as itś in paramiko, cd to directory; permission editing; removing files/folders; creating folders; copying files/folders from PC to Device; etc.

Comment: Advanced Necropost:

Pexpect, specifically pxssh, http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pxssh.html

Does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Even if I would use pem keys for this and this is an old topic, I also wanted to quote [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script: https://github.com/aprey10/ssh-authorizer

It also allows to skip ssh keys passphrase request.