# Automate SSH login and programmatically induce remote, interactive shell

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, ssh

I'm working from Mac OSX and am trying to create a script that will `ssh user@host` and subsequently change the working directory (cd) from within the virtual server.

Googling indicated that `ssh -t user@host "command goes here"` would allow for this, but when I enter `cd /my/path` it says that there is no such directory. It also forces me to exit the server. What is the best, simplest way to accomplish this?

Comment: `man ssh` knows better than Google: *"If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell."*

Comment: Yes, I want an interactive shell on the remote server with a new working directory. Can you give me some advice about automating authentication or point me in the direction of a resource that could help? Let's say I opt to authenticate manually (pw), how would I go about opening an interactive shell and changing the directory?

Comment: "Assist web development" doesn't actually strengthen your case for this being a programming question -- interactive shell operations are human operations rather than programmatic ones, just like editing text is, and we don't consider questions about how to use emacs or vi (as opposed to how to script them) on-topic here either. The reason to consider this question on-topic (and I **do** consider it on-topic) is that it's _programatically_ creating a remote interactive shell; if you want to emphasize topicality, it should be edited to lean on that.

Comment: Thanks for your insight on this. Title changed to reflect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that the desired end result is a remote *interactive* shell, in the desired target directory, which you can interact with from your keyboard. If not, please clarify the question.

---

Force a TTY with the `-t` argument to ssh and spawn an interactive shell with an explicit invocation of `bash -i`:

```
ssh -t user@host "cd /my/path && exec bash -i"
```

Scripting/automating the authentication is road already well-traveled (and, thus, duplicative); see existing questions such as [Bash: controlling SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924464/bash-controlling-ssh) for assistance on that matter.