# Mysql redirect traffic to another server

Tags: mysql, redirect, proxy, portforwarding

is it possible to redirect entire  mysql query to another server?

I've have many apps in differents server that comunicate with a single database (windows machine).

For transfer database (to a linux server) without change any IP inside many many php files (there are a lot of things that i don't know because is not my creation but is my legacy) there's something i can do?
Proxy?port forwarding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik, mysql implementations don't offer this functionality, however, you can "proxy" connections using an ssh tunnel like this:

```
ssh -N ssh-user@host.domain -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306
```

This requires an ssh-server on the host that serves the mysql (on port 3306) and you having ssh-access to that machine. You run the command on the machine your php is excecuted from, then you can, as long as it runs, access the mysql host on "localhost". All requests will be securely tunneled to the remote mysql server.

The -L switch instructs ssh to forward tcp connections on local port 3306 to port 3306 on the machine you ssh to.

The -N switch instructs ssh to do just that and not run a command.

If you add the -f switch, the command will immidiately fork into background, which may be useful for this usecase.

You probably also want to use [passwordless ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21467504/4866865)

However, this is probably not a clean solution for production. I use this method only for development purposes and I'd suggest you fix your codebase on the long run (i.e. put your mysql configuration in a central place).

Comment: i need to implement it to my linux clients? no solution for server side? remember that is windows server

Comment: You'll sure be able to serve ssh on a windows server with no problems. If you're running your php on a windows server, you may need to install openssh to use these command line switches.

Comment: If your client (from a mysql perspective; Where the php runs, not the mysql-server) is windows server and you don't want to install openssh there: Other ssh clients offer port forwarding as well.