# Linux automatically transfers files through scp without a password

Tags: linux, cron, scp, ssh-keys

I now want to know how to execute an instll.sh file, and then transfer the file to another vm regularly through scp without entering a password

Here I define the party that transmits the file as vmA, and the party that receives the file as vmB

I can only do it after executing instll.sh, Iinstall.sh will create ssh key in vmA, and then transfer id_rsa.pub to the authorized_key file of vmB, but when I execute install.sh, he will execute the scp command If the error **Host key verification failed. lost connection** appears, I have to manually execute the scp command once, and then it will start to automatically execute the transmission work (I use crontab to automatically execute scp)

Explain what install.sh does

1. Copy some files to their respective directories, such as the files I want to transfer and cronatb..
2. Restart the crontab service
3. Please ignore it
4. Please ignore it
5. Automatically generate ssh key
6. Transfer the ssh key to the authorized_keys file of vmB
7. Execute the scp command once so that the connections on both sides can be successfully connected

**When executing point 7, I will be asked to enter a password**

[image]

Because this install.sh will be on different vm later, such as vmA, vmC, vmD, vmE, and they all need to transfer the data to vmB, I would like to ask if there is a way to execute the install.sh, just It will start to help me execute the work of spc without entering a password, and it can work normally

Comment: Look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449932/ssh-autologin-without-using-keys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to establish ssh key pair when "Host key verification failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161548/how-to-establish-ssh-key-pair-when-host-key-verification-failed)